# Datastructure for a factory pattern in practice

Tags: design-patterns, patterns-and-practices

I'm implementing what's basically an event log system for a larger system.  I used Single-table inheritance to build out the table.

The problem I'm having is figuring out how to build out the classes from the database.  It's easy enough for me to figure out what they are to load them into the database, but to pull them out and create objects and collections out of them is a little trickier.  The only way I know of is to have a switch statement and hope that if someone implements a new object that they'll update the switch, but that doesn't seem practical.

I'm sure I'm getting something wrong about how I'm thinking of the factory pattern here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at how Hibernate does it. See the [SingleTableEntityPersister](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/persister/entity/SingleTableEntityPersister.java) if you are truly using single-table inheritance.

Or better yet... just use Hibernate/NHibernate or another ORM and don't reinvent the wheel.

To be clear, I'm not a huge fan of ORMs, but phrases like "single-table inheritance" imply that you're already trying to object-relational mapping the "manual" way, and you'd save yourself a lot of time by using a tool that does all the heavy lifting for you.

If you *must* do it yourself for whatever reason... well, as you can see, there are different methods, but typically you will need to use a discriminator column, and for that you will either need a map, a switch statement, or a consistent convention (e.g. the discriminator value has an obvious relationship to the class name and you can instantiate it directly with reflection). Switch statement is going to be the fastest and is probably the preferred approach for a fairly small number of derived classes.

Tools like Hibernate can't do it that way because, obviously, it would require specialized knowledge about the specific hierarchy, which they don't have. You *do* have that knowledge, so you can skip all the mapping/reflection and just use switch/case in a factory class somewhere. The fact that someone might forget to update it in the future isn't really an argument... your factory should throw an exception as soon as it encounters an unknown discriminator value.

If you're really that worried, make the discriminator an enum, and write a unit test for the factory that iterates through every known enum value and tries to instantiate it with the factory. That way the future maintenance programmer will find out right away if they missed something.

Comment: The problem I have with tools that do it for you is when you get into inheritance I've usually had to do a lot of manual mapping myself (see asp.NET MVC).  I haven't seen Hibernate, I'll take a look at that hough.

Comment: @Snowburnt: NHibernate and Fluent NHibernate have auto-mapping. But even if they didn't, is a few lines of mapping *really* worse than hundreds of lines of code?

Comment: It's a good point, one I'll have to think about.  Generally I'd prefer something that makes the most sense semantically and for a clean database design, also reusability.  if I can reuse those hundreds of lines of code then it's worth it.

Comment: @Snowburnt: Code usually has to be tested in several different applications before it can be considered "reusable". I don't see how it's worth it, considering that the *reusable* code has *already* been written - that's *exactly* what ORMs are for, and most of them don't place any special constraints on your database design, so it's as "clean" as you want it to be.

Comment: So why aren't you a fan of ORMs?

Comment: @Snowburnt: I dislike database abstractions in general because I consider queries to be part of the business logic and prefer to work directly with the relational model and specific flavour of SQL whenever possible (which makes for code that is more verbose, but simpler to understand). I also design databases for normalization and performance, not as an afterthought to the object model. This clearly doesn't apply to your current situation because, if it did, you wouldn't be asking about how to map inheritance - that's very much an object-relational mapping concern.

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to go halfsies, though, unless you *really* know what you're doing. If you're not really a database guy and just want to think of the database as a way of persisting object graphs (which is when you'd try to model something like polymorphism) then use an ORM. If you're a "data first" kind of developer then use DTOs that have exactly the same structure as your tables. If you try to do both at the same time, you're liable to confuse other people (and occasionally yourself).

Comment: I guess that's probably my problem, I'm a bit of an amateur at programming.  Years of training, just not much professional experience.  The few things I have made have been small scale and relatively easy to maintain.  I got a lot of OOP training and done a lot of research and, it's fascinating to me.  The one thing they never really got around to talking about is how do you store the stuff?  In a memory persistent system it doesn't seem like it matters, it's all handled by the code. I know my database stuff and I'm trying to get to thinking OOP.  I think you can abstract to a point...

Comment: and keep the query data as limited as possible and in as few places as possible, which seems to be one of the primary goals of ORMs (it does go a step further and remove your ability to make queries at all).  I like being able to do my own queries and make them as secure and extensible as they need to be.  Probably after I make a few of these apps I'll get sick of it and use an ORM (or if I work on a simple enough app or something I'm not as personally invested in(this is a bit of a hobby application)).  Thanks for the conversation, it was really helpful!